# Why VS Code search got merged into git window

Tags: visual-studio-code

The left menu bar don't have the search anymore, when I clicked on git, realized the search is inside the git.. How to move it out, tried resetting the user settings, and it didn't help. Anybody faced/fixed this before?

[image]

Comment: Just drag from the `Search` header to the Activity Bar on the left.

Comment: Thank you @Mark for answering it before the Question got closed.